# i need a session variable to change from page to page as i move from one page to another vb.net

Tags: vb.net, session, asp.net

i am new to this. i have 4 pages. login.aspx, account.aspx, settings.aspx and fliers.aspx.
its all programmed in vb.net with sql server backend.
on my firstr page, login.aspx i have this code in the .vb page -

```
Dim SQL As String = "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE email='" + Me.txtUserName.Text + "' AND password='" + Me.txtPassword.Text + "' "
ExecuteNonQuery(SQL)
SqlCmd = New SqlCommand(SQL, SqlCnn)
SqlDR = SqlCmd.ExecuteReader
If SqlDR.HasRows Then
    Do While SqlDR.Read()
        Label1.Text = "successfully logged in"
        Dim webUser As New webUser(SqlDR("email"), Session.Item("sqlcnn"))
        Session.Item("webUser") = webUser
        isValidUser = True
    Loop
Else
    Label1.Text = "Failed to login"
End If
```

as u can see it takes session.item("webuser") as email. this is fine on this page. on the next page that is account.aspx, it needs to replace email with the ID of the user who las logged in and in the settings.aspx page, it needs to replace the id of user with the profile id of that user. All these tables r in backend and have data, but the problem is my lack of knowledge. 
How do i make the session have different variables in it.

Answer (score 1):

Yikes.  You have tremendous security issues with your code:

**SQL Injection Attacks**
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998271.aspx

Also, you should use the Membership provider and Forms-based authentication:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301240

Lastly, to set a session value simply say `Session( "Value Name" ) = value`

Answer (score 0):

reiut consider getting rid of inline sql and using exec.  Look into stored procedures and passing parameters using the command object.  Passwords should also not be stored as plain text.

As for sessions they are simply just variables that can be changed in say the page_load event.

For instance,

Session("FirstName") = "Jon"

The session, FirstName, has the value Jon.  It can easily be changed in another aspx page simply by resetting it:

In another page:

Session("FirstName") = "Dawn"

Try it out.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is actually to create a class object (after you've read the links from @Nissan Fan and started using some kind of secured authentication) and store the serialized class object into the session. Your class object should inherit the System.Security.Principal.GenericIdentity class or at the very least implement IIdentity. Then you could just grab it out of session, cast it, and access the properties of your object directly (username/email/whatever).